# Exporting data from the list-view control into a text file/excel and importing it back into the listview control when needed

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-automation

My program has output data to the Listview control. Now I would like to export the data to a text file/excel and then load it back to the listview control when I need to. I know how to do both these tasks using the listbox control but listview is new to me. I've been researching and playing around with code for hours but I keep getting one error or the other. Kindly find the latest version of my code to export data below. Also, if you could provide code to import, that would be super.

```
   'Export the listview to an Excel spreadsheet

     Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
     SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
     SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files 
     (*.xlsx)|*.xslx"
     SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

   'exit if no file selected
     If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
     Exit Sub
     End If

    'create objects to interface to Excel
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim placeholder As String

  'create a workbook and get reference to first worksheet
  xls.Workbooks.Add()
  book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
  sheet = book.ActiveSheet

  'step through rows and columns and copy data to worksheet

   Dim row As Integer = 1
   Dim col As Integer = 1

   For Each item As ListViewItem In lstViewUsers.Items
    For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
        placeholder = sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
        col = col + 1
    Next
    row += 1
```

[image: Data]
[image: Error]

Comment: I googled "save listview data to text file vb.net" and got About 1,420,000 results (0.81 seconds) . Give it a try.

Comment: @Mary, I did try that and I got a lot of results like you suggest however I couldn't tweak any of them to meet my particular needs. Thankfully though I found a way around it. Thanks for your input.